# how to write link parser with regex

Tags: regex

I have a line: "a herf = sdfsjkdhfks http://www.google.com  134"

I want to get the "http://www.google.com" part only if there is a "<" at the beginning and a ">" in the end

For now my regex is "(?i)(http)(s:| :).+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}/?"

What can I do to check if the arrow bracket exist without taking it as part of my regular expression, I mean, I do not want arrow bracket to be the output of the match"

In this case, the output should be null cause there is no arrow bracket, but if there are, I want the output to be just "www.google.com"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Attempting to use regex to parse HTML is capricious. Do you *know* that there will never be a different attribute between the `a` and the `href`? Are you prepared to cope with arbitrary Javascript? Etc etc etc.

Comment: @tripleee It need not be a complete html code to be parsed . There may be cases for message boards etc, where databases are stored with records having such content. Or may be something else where its needed. And he didn't specify his actual purpose for finding such pattern to assume anything.

Comment: @AkshayHazari Those details should be explained in the question.  If you have requirements which are not properly documented, you will receive answers which are wrong, insufficient, too simple, too complex, or just ... as bad as the question.

Comment: @tripleee . I don't think he needs to specify whether he is going to parse a file or a record. Its not a bad question if he asks with an input and an output explaining what he wants and giving what he tried . Its being too unreasonable if by assuming anything you want to vote it negative.

Comment: @AkshayHazari The issue here is that this smacks of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but there isn't enough information to decide. With more context, we could tell whether the approach is sane at all, or perhaps what to suggest instead.

Answer (score -1):

Include the bracket as part of your regex, then as a second step after you've found the match, strip it out of that result string before you return the result.

If you're anchoring the angled brackets to the start and end of the regex, this could be as simple as something like .substring(1,matchedString.length()-1).

Answer (score -1):

This will get the link part skipping any thing at the start and end.

```
import re
content  = "<ahref = 123 http://googl 235>"
re.findall("<a[\s]*href[\s]*=.*(http://[^> ]*)[\s]*.*>",content)
```

Comment: I think you got your brackets flipped.

Comment: It also seems like you're ignoring the regex in the question.